# Bootstrap 4 with angular and theming

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

The following is not working, yet is as per official docs, so I am completely stuck.

My html is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
```

And the contents of my scss is:

```
$theme-colors: ( primary: #d8b990, dark:#16161d);

$primary: theme-color("primary");
// MY STYLES
.navbar {
    background-color: $primary !important;
 }

 // Required
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
 // Optional
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

The setup is current Bootstrap with angular 8 plus ng-bootstrap installed. No jQuery or popper.

Comment: i think in the 2nd line of your scss does the theme-color refer to the 1st line? if yes then this could be a typo and you would need to replace the variable name in your 1st line to $theme-color instead

Comment: can this help you? https://github.com/id1945/ng-multi-bootstrap-themes

Comment: I think you need to move the imports up

Comment: Ive tried it without the second line. Ive tried using inverted commas, Ive tried moving the the imports up. Nothing takes effect. The multi theme doesnt help me.

Comment: @MichelleDiamond Imports should be moved up, otherwise what are you overriding? Right now what is happening is that bootstrap variables are overriding your own values.